# Flash Pro IDE can't find RadioButton

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I tried to build a little quiz with AS3, Flash & XML.
When I create a radiobutton Flash creates automatically an import at the top of my document. Fine!

But when I will test my scene I got an error:
1172: Definition fl.controls.RadioButton not found

```
var rb:RadioButton = new RadioButton();
rb.x = 50;
rb.y = 150;
rb.label = "Testbutton";
rb.value = "100";
```

Why?

So for the case that I damaged something on my laptop I installed the new 30-days trial version on my other PC ... but the same error.
The flash.swc is like in every Flash Pro IDE in their own directory structure.
So that can't be the failure.
The auto-complete shows me all possible import-statements also 
"import fl.controls.RadioButton"

Does anybody knows that problem?
Why only the RadioButton?

Answer (score 1):

You must import to Library Panel from Window-Components.

refer a following image

[image]
[image]

And you should import Radiobutton as follows:

```
import fl.controls.RadioButton;

var rb:RadioButton = new RadioButton();
rb.x = 50;
rb.y = 150;
rb.label = "Testbutton";
rb.value = "100";
```

Comment: Ok, now it works. :-)
Thank you!
But why have I to set this components first into the the library?
When I want to create it from scratch only with AS3 it won't work?
Thats' sad!
I can import these classes in AS3 but to use them I first have to put them into the library?

Comment: Yes, must put into library. As you know, UI Components is very heavy. ready test when takes quite a long time. so i guess, Adobe not set default AS3 Library. Be exactly the other reason.